# How to catch exceptions in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, c++builder

My web server is based on Delphi / DataSnap. 
When a server method raises an exception, how can I handle it?

I tried `Application.OnException` but it does not work because each connection is a new thread and it only works for the IDE thread.

I want to manage them for adding the data in a log file.

**UPDATE:**

As @Remy Lebeau says, I do not have control aver the creation of the thread. It is a DataSnap based application that works as Web Api server. A `TDSServerClass` components instances my `TServerMethods` class. Then, when a web connection arrives, DataSnap creates a new thread and call to my `TServerMethods` methods. If within the method, a exception is raised, then it is lost because each thread has its stack. With `Application.OnException`, I only can catch unhandheld exceptions from the IDE thread. What I want to do is to log any handheld exception in a log file.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the architecture of this process, and whether or not you have any control over the threads. And if not why they are raising at all.

Comment: "*DataSnap creates a new thread and call to my `TServerMethods` methods. If within the method, a exception is raised, then it is lost*" - why can't you catch exceptions raised in your own methods? Put a `try/except` inside your method, log it, and then re-`raise` it for DataSnap to handle as needed.

Comment: Yeah. Why are you letting the exceptions leak?

Comment: Yes, it is what I will do, 'try/except' in each method. I wanted to avoid it because I have more than 200 methods and it seems to me too repetitive. (try, catch, log, throw,). Managing unhanheld exceptions leave the code cleaner, shorter, and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

From the [System.Classes.TThread.FatalException](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TThread.FatalException) documentation:

> If the Execute method raises an exception that is not caught and handled within that method, the thread terminates and sets **FatalException** to the exception object for that exception. Applications can check **FatalException** from an OnTerminate event handler to determine whether the thread terminated due to an exception.

If an exception occurs in the `Execute` method of a `TThread` object its `FatalException` property is assigned and the thread terminates.

You can check if an exception occurred in a thread implementing its `OnTerminate` event:

```
procedure TForm1.YourThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ex: Exception;
begin
  ex := Exception(TYourThread(Sender).FatalException);
  if Assigned(ex) then
    //an exception has occurred: your code here
end;
```

This is how you can assign the event to you thread:

```
var
  yourThread: TYourThread;
begin
  yourThread := TYourThread.Create(True);
  yourThread.OnTerminate := YourThreadTerminate;
  yourThread.Start;
end;
```

Comment: This is assuming the OP is creating his/her own threads. The OP said DataSnap is being used, so the threads are likely internally to that and not directly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to hook into the exception handling mechanism itself - [JCL](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/JCL_2.6/jcl/source/windows/JclHookExcept.pas) has code that does that, for example, or you could use third party libraries like [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm), [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/details_delphi.php) or others. They also collect stack traces and other info useful to understand what lead to an exception.
I used JCL some time ago in a Datasnap DCOM server to log unhandled exception to a custom event log. If you're going to write to a file, beware of concurrent access, because more than one thread could try to write to it. Also [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx) (ETW) may be a a better, although more complex way, to log to a file for diagnostic purposes.
Anyway, in this kind of applications, it's better to handle "expected" exceptions, and never let them propagate up to a generic handler. Of course, being able to trap and log "unexpected" ones is useful.